# Does DTM implementation with header code in <body> effect the implementation

Tags: dynamic, tags, adobe, adobe-analytics

Does DTM implementation with header code in body effect the implementation. Our client has been using the sitecatalyst with the current implementation from last 8 months. We dont see any discrepency in data collection. But the Client placed both header and footer code at the end of the body tag.

Does it result in any discrepencies and can we continue with the current implementation of header code in body for future integrations such as opinion lab,Media tags,Remarketing tags,Adobe Target.

However, Adobe strogly suggests not to do so.
https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/dtm/code.html

We would like to continue with current implementation if it doesnt make any difference.Please help

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The dual snippets allow users to precisely time rules for page load,
>   enabling scripts, tools, and tags to be triggered at page top, page
>   bottom, DOM ready, onload, or upon user interaction (or any other time
>   of your choosing).
>   http://www.searchdiscovery.com/satellite/adobedtm-faq/#faq39

It will affect the timing of when your tags get fired.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. It helps me to get the answer

Answer (score 0):

It's more than strongly suggests.  Not installing the code as prescribed makes it a non-supported implementation.

Comment: yes Rudi adobe strongly recommends this, but I was intrested in knowing why the case is so. Thanks for help